# replacing div content with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do this with pure javascript, not with jquery. I have a div that has an id `test` and contains other divs inside it. How do I empty the content of this div and replace it with other html?

```
<div id="test">
   <div>...</div>
   <div>...</div>
   <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "new content"
```

Answer (score 25):

clear the div:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '';
```

replace it :

```
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
h1.innerHTML = "hello world!";
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(h1);
```

Answer (score 5):

Off the top of my head, I think this should work....

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think the -1 comes from `innerHtml` not being `innerHTML`. I'll upvote to counter; that's mean.

Answer (score 5):

Use `document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ''`.

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Some other Content";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");
testDiv.innerHTML = "<h5>It works!</h5>";
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also an

```
Element.replaceWith()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith