# web page slightly altered from index page

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

The question is fairly simple, yet I've been looking around for an hour and found nothing:

make a page that is exactly the same as the home page, but a specific div has altered content

## example index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* css goes here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="stay">I wont change</div>
    <div id="change">I will change</div>
</body>
</html>
```

so I want to be able to code a page so that it inherits the entire html from the index page (WITHOUT COPYING THE CODE), but a specific div (here with the id `#change`) to have different content. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What action triggers the change?

Comment: it's not an action...it's a different page with the same layout and everything as the index page, but with one divs content altered...i doubt the only way to do this is copy the entire index page code again and change that one div

Comment: You should look at template-engines, like Smarty. There you can split the tempalte up in head and footer, and the main-content the part that is different from page to page. Makes everything a lot cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: @RyanSaxe So is there a button or something that leads you to this other page? How do you get to the other "page"? Why not just use JavaScript? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173691/replacing-div-content-with-javascript

Comment: this was more a conceptual "do i really have to copy and paste the entire html and change it or can i do something less brute"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really "inherit" code snippets, but I understand that you're trying to reuse the page content. From your posted code, it's hard to tell exactly how the change differs from the index. Is it just a content change or does the index page not have that div?

You have a couple of options. If just the content of the div is changing, you could use the same php page and then use jquery to change the content of the div, so something like

index.php

```
<? php include("page.php"); ?>
```

other page

```
<? php include("page.php"); ?>
// javascript to modify div
```

You could break the page into chunks and just include them as needed, so you could have a top.php and a bottom.php, and the index page could do

```
<? php include("top.php"); ?>
<? php include("bottom.php"); ?>
```

And then your similar page could do something like

```
<? php include("top.php"); ?>
// custom stuff here
<? php include("bottom.php"); ?>
```

If neither of these solutions work you could always use a templating engine to create a page template, though that may be a little much for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have tagged this question in `php` So, I will give you answer inclusive of php implementation.

Create 3 pages. `index.php` `about.php` and `foo.php`

The objective is to show some content in `index.php` but  all content in `about.php`

Call this page `foo.php`

```
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
        <p> Show this in index.php </p>
        <?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] === 'about.php'):  ?>
        <p> Show this in about.php </p>
        <?php endif;  ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now, all you have to do is ... include `foo.php` in both pages.

Answer (score 0):

Make the page you want and you can go about doing this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* css goes here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="stay">I wont change</div>
    <?php
      if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "other-page.php")){ ?>   

      <div id="change">I will change</div>

      <?php }else{ ?>

      <div id="change">Original div</div>

      <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

That takes the file name and based on that you can change content (if is only for one page, otherwise write a function/class based on that).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here are two, each with their own advantages and disadvantages.

Firstly, if you don't want to modify the page at all, you can add a small PHP code segment which will include a page passed in through the GET variable. For example

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* css goes here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="stay">I wont change</div>
    <div id="change"><?php require($_GET['page']); ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

would mean that using the URL `mypage.php?page=home.php` would automatically include the contents of a file called home.php into that div.

Another way to do it is to divide up that page into 2 sections, and including both of them in any other page you use. For example, splitting the code into 2 seperate files, such as

top.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* css goes here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="stay">I wont change</div>
    <div id="change">
```

bottom.php:

```
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then in your PHP file you can use the following

```
require("top.php);
MY CONTENT HERE
require("bottom.php);
```

remember that you will need to use echo to output html code on this method if it is within `<?php` and `?>` tags

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this will plain HTML.

To do it in php, first create template file like so: (template.php)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    * css goes here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="stay">I wont change</div>
    <div id="change"><?=$main_content?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, let's say you want to make a "contact me" page.

```
<?php
    // in contact.php
    $main_content = "Contact me at my@email.com

    include "template.php";
?>
```

This will write the contents of template.php to the page and echo out the value of $main_content  inside div#change

Now, this is generally frowned upon because managing your variables becomes difficult as the size of the template increases. To keep things sane, use a templating engine as all of the other answers are suggesting.