# Replace content/section button webdesign

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a way to make a replace button on my page. I've looked around the web but all I found was a replace text script. What I want is to replace both the text in my `h1` tag and the text in the article. If its possible to just replace the whole `div` with another `div` it would be great.

To explain a bit more accurate on my page: www.bravitus.com
I want at the "OM MIG" section, a button where I could switch out the content, for something else like some info about bravitus. I'd like a button to click that replaces only the orange section.

Here's a bit of my mark-up:

```
<div class="full-page" id="page-2">
<div class="container">
    <h1 style="color:white;" >Hvem er jeg</h1>
    <div class="columns eight"><article> Lorem ipsum </article>
</div>
```

I want to replace all content in the page-2, or just switch out the whole page-2 `div` with another.

Is that possible?

Comment: Have a look at jQuery's replaceWith(): http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: possible duplicate of [replacing div content with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173691/replacing-div-content-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go, [a small demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/json/8cu34y4L/) (http://jsfiddle.net/json/8cu34y4L/).

There are three buttons with the `data-switch` attribute. The attribute indicates what block inside the `page-2` will be shown, when the button is clicked.

HTML

```
<button data-switch="#about_me">Click to read about me</button>
<button data-switch="#education">Click to show my education</button>
<button data-switch="#about_name_bravitus">Click to read about the name Bravitus</button>

<div id="page-2">

    <div id="about_me" class="container">
         <h1>This is about me section</h1>

        <div>about me about me about me</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Hidden blocks that you show when the appropriate button is clicked. -->
    <div id="education" class="container" style="display: none;">
         <h1>This is about my education</h1>

        <div>education education education</div>
    </div>

    <div id="about_name_bravitus" class="container" style="display: none;">
         <h1>This is about the name bravitus</h1>

        <div>bravitus bravitus bravitus</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS (you need jQuery)

```
// Listening to a button click.
$('[data-switch]').on('click', function (e) {
    var $page = $('#page-2'),
        blockToShow = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-switch');

    // Hide all children.
    $page.children().hide();

    // And show the requested component.
    $page.children(blockToShow).show();
});
```

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot man!! thats one hell of a christmas gift for me :P

Comment: Ok somethings not working as is is suppose to, im doing something wrong, i even tried a clean file, but it sems that it isn't using the script, hmm.

I've placed the script inside script tags and then the <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
In the head tag

Comment: @ThomasRavnholt Yes, you got it exactly right. jQuery should be in the `<head>`. The code snippet from the answer should be, desirably, as close to the `</body>` as possible, wrapped with `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` or simply `$(function () { ... })` so it executes only when the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood what you want.

But if you just want to replace all html inside page-2, you simply can do that (with jQuery):

```
var html = // Here comes your html
$('#page-2').html(html);
```

Comment: What i want is some buttons that changes the content, so instead of having 3 individual sections, i just want a button that can change the content in the section. 

Like this:

Button1 - Button2 - Button3

click Button1= shows info about me

click button2= shows info about my education

click button3= shows info about the name bravitus.


So when one of these buttons are clicked, it change
s all content in the section, to something else.

Comment: everything else on the page has to stay the same, except the content in the orange section, it has to change when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: But you can use the .html() used in my answer to change the content. Is anything wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

So im not sure if this is the correct way but what i ended up doing was this

```
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("fisk").innerHTML = "Hvem er du"
}

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Now i just have to find a way to make it replace more than text. to replace divs and other tags all together.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this link and execute the below code:

script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"

Click to read about me
Click to show my education
Click to read about the name Bravitus

```
<div id="about_me" class="container">
     <h1>This is about me section</h1>

    <div>about me about me about me</div>
</div>

<!-- Hidden blocks that you show when the appropriate button is clicked. -->
<div id="education" class="container" style="display: none;">
     <h1>This is about my education</h1>

    <div>education education education</div>
</div>

<div id="about_name_bravitus" class="container" style="display: none;">
     <h1>This is about the name bravitus</h1>

    <div>bravitus bravitus bravitus</div>
</div>
```

JS (you need jQuery)

```
// Listening to a button click.
$('[data-switch]').on('click', function (e) 
{
var $page = $('#page-2'),
blockToShow = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-switch');

// Hide all children.
$page.children().hide();

// And show the requested component.
$page.children(blockToShow).show();
});
```

Comment: This does not look as a proper answer, you're just adding the JQuery link, a comment would be better and will avoid downvotes

Comment: try posting a complete solution instead of the answer above because technically this doesn't solve anything